# What is the correct way of using secrets in strategy-matrix pattern in GitHub Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions for one of the projects. I have a use case when I need to deploy to 2 different environments. As the number of domains may grow, I want to deploy to all of them at once parametrically.

Part of my job that fails:

```
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        domain: [['main', 'books-v1'], ['old-main', 'books-v2']]
```

The above part works perfectly but if I need to add new variants from the secrets, the workflow doesn't work. See the snippet below:

```
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        domain: [['main', 'books-v1', ${{ secrets.URL_V1 }}], ['old-main', 'books-v2', ${{ secrets.URL_V2 }}]]
```

I checked [GitHub Actions docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-activity-types). I also searched available examples on GitHub to see existing solutions. So far, I didn't find a similar use case.

Is there a way to make it work like that? What are alternatives to my approach that will work?

GitHub Actions failure message:

> You have an error in your yaml syntax on line XYZ

Comment: Use single quotes around `${{ secrets... }}`.

Comment: @Azeem Can you give a more precise example, please? '${{ secrets... }}'  - like this doesn't work

Comment: What did you try? Like this `domain: [['main', 'books-v1', '${{ secrets.URL_V1 }}'], ...`?

Comment: @Azeem Exactly this syntax. `domain: [['main', 'books-v1', '${{ secrets.URL_V1 }}'], ...`

Comment: Right. I thought that was just a syntax error. Single quotes do fix that; but, the `secrets` context is not allowed under `strategy`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability.

Comment: An alternative could be to use the `vars` context. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context. You can store these values at the org, repo, or environment level and use those here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the YAML level, single quotes around `${{ secrets... }}` should fix the syntax error.

But, according to the [Context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability), the `secrets` context is not allowed under `stratey`. The allowed contexts are:

```
jobs.<job_id>.strategy      github, needs, vars, inputs
```

You can make use of the [`vars` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) for your use case.

Apart from that, linting your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ would be much faster to identify potential issues.

---

**UPDATE** (by [Dmytro Chasovskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473386/dmytro-chasovskyi))

Here is an example with the `vars` context:

With a variable `DOMAINS` having this config:

```json
{
   "v1": {
     "url": "http://localhost:80/api/v1"
   },
   "v2": {
     "url": "http://localhost:80/api/v2"
   }
}
```

the workflow will be:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        domain: [['main', 'books-v1', '${{ vars.DOMAINS.v1.url }}'], ['old-main', 'books-v2', '${{ vars.DOMAINS.v2.url }}']]
```